# Star Wars: Rebel Assault I + II on Steam shows blank white screen on MacBook Pro M1

Tags: technical-issues, macos, star-wars-rebel-assault-2

I downloaded *Star Wars: Rebel Assault I + II* on Steam to my MacBook Pro M1 running macOS Ventura 13.3.1. However, whenever I try to run it, I get a blank white fullscreen window that I can only exit using <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>. Is there a fix for this problem? I encountered [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/456540/discussions/0/5624408883144526251/) on Steam Support but it is unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this problem, follow these steps

1. Open up the directory `~/Library/Application Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Star Wars - Rebel Assault 1 and 2`.
2. After that, open up `dosbox_rebel.conf` and `dosbox_rebel2.conf` with `TextEdit`.
3. Change: `output=overlay` to `output=opengl`